# Get string between parts

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vba

I am having a string:

```
c(\\", \"Â \", \"Â \", \"\", \"\", \"Object:\", \"\", \"\", NA, \"vlg. numb 2\", \"\", NA, NA, NA, NA, \"This:Â \", NA, \"Date\r\n(21.03.1961)\", \"K..\r\nRom (28.04.2012)\", NA, NA, \"test.test@yahoo.de\", NA, \"Italy, Rome\", NA, \"UP,Â Ã–\", \"BP,Â \", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)"
```

I would like to  get the string `numb 2`, which is between `vlg.numb 2\"`

I tried:

```
=MID(A18;FIND("vlg.";A18;1)+7;FIND("/object";A18;1)-FIND("\";A18;1)-8)
```

However, I only get `#VALUE` back.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does this work? `=MID(B48,SEARCH("vlg.",B48)+LEN("vlg."),SEARCH("\"",",B48)+LEN("\"","))`  (assuming of course your string is in cell `B48`.

Comment: You mean `=MID(A18,FIND("vlg.",A18)+5,6)`?

Comment: @findwindow Your formula is working, but the string I am searching for has a different length for every other string I am searching for.Hence, all strings that are longer than 5 are cut of.

Comment: Then please provide more sample data/clarify requirement.

Comment: @findwindow Sample data: `c(\\", \"Â \", \"Â \", \"\", \"\", \"Object:\", \"\", \"\", NA, \"vlg. test object is long\", \"\", NA, NA, NA, NA, \"This:Â \", NA, \"Date\r\n(21.03.1961)\", \"K..\r\nRom (28.04.2012)\", NA, NA, \"test.test@yahoo.de\", NA, \"Italy, Rome\", NA, \"UP,Â Ã–\", \"BP,Â \", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)"
`

Comment: So whatever follows `vlg.` and before the first \?

Comment: Thx for your answer! My basic requirements are, that I want to parse the string when `vlg.` occurs up to `\"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
=MID(A18,FIND("vlg.",A18)+5,FIND("\""",A18,FIND("vlg.",A18))-FIND("vlg.",A18)-5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Say A1 is your string, A2 is your start search, and A3 is your end search:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(A2,A1)+LEN(A2),FIND(A3,A1,FIND(A2,A1)+LEN(A2))-FIND(A2,A1)-LEN(A2))
```